# App crash when i click on the registered user fragment in my app .. which contains the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to fetch all the users registered on my app and stored in the Firebase database .. I have written the following code. But when i run the app and click on registered_users fragment(New_regActivity)it does not show anything and most of the time the app crashes
The main activity which will show all users is coded like this

```
    public class New_regActivity extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AdapterUsers adapterUsers;
    List<User> userList;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup Container, @NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_newreg, Container, false);
    recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapterUsers= new AdapterUsers(getActivity(),userList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    getAllUsers();

    return view;
}

private void getAllUsers() {
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser= 
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference reference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User users = ds.getValue(User.class);
                if (users.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                    userList.add(users);
                }
                adapterUsers = new AdapterUsers(getActivity(),userList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

And the AdapterUsers class was written like this

```
    public class AdapterUsers extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterUsers.MyHolder> {
Context context;
List<User> userList;

public AdapterUsers(Context context, List<User> userList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userList = userList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = 
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
    String fullname= userList.get(position).getName();
    String username= userList.get(position).getUser_Name();
    final String email= userList.get(position).getEmail_Address();

    holder.mNameTV.setText(fullname);
    holder.mUsernameTV.setText(username);
    holder.mEmailTV.setText(email);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,""+email,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
       return userList.size();
}

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView mNameTV,mEmailTV,mUsernameTV;

    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mNameTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameTV);
        mEmailTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Email_AddressTV);
        mUsernameTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.User_NameTV);
    }
}
```

}

The model class i have made is

```
    public class User {
public String Name, User_Name, Email_Address,uid;

public User() {

}

public User(String name, String user_Name, String email_Address, String uid) {
    Name = name;
    User_Name = user_Name;
    Email_Address = email_Address;
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getUser_Name() {
    return User_Name;
}

public void setUser_Name(String user_Name) {
    User_Name = user_Name;
}

public String getEmail_Address() {
    return Email_Address;
}

public void setEmail_Address(String email_Address) {
    Email_Address = email_Address;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
```

}

And i got the following exception and error in the logcat section

```
    2020-08-30 14:54:29.195 13312-13312/com.shadab.login E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.shadab.login, PID: 13312
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean  
 .lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.shadab.login.java.New_regActivity$1.onDataChange(New_regActivity.java:56)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)


The line 56 is 

    if (!(user.getUid()).equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: it says that adapter is not attached to recyclerview

Comment: That's not an error, that's a warning. If the app crashes, you should get an Exception. Please find it and add it to your question.

Comment: Yeah i have added the exception in the question now

Comment: Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Use **this** on all fields and refactor your code something like this.

```
public class User {
public String name, userName, emailAddress, uid;

public User() {

}

public User(String name, String userName, String emailAddress, String uid) {
    this.name = name;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.emailAddress = emailAdress;
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUser_Name(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getEmailAddress() {
    return this.emailAddress;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    Email_Address = email_Address;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
```

Comment: I have resolved it .. But now some other type of error comes up .. I have mentioned it in the question.. Please check it